# socket.io events and custom events

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

```
connection
disconnect
custom-event
```

Are these string available somewhere on the `socket` object on the server-side? in case the socket object is passed around, otherwise I'll passing another param with event as well and function signature would be as follows.

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
   doSomething(socket, 'connection');

   socket.on('disconnect', function(){
       doSomething(socket', 'disconnect');
   }
}


function doSomething(socket, eventName) { 
    // is there a way to get this event name from socket object itself?

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are these string available somewhere on the socket object on the server-side?

No.  If you want an event name passed to your function, you need to pass it yourself like your own example shows.  It is not part of the `socket` object because (with async operations in-flight) multiple events could be in-flight at the same time so the `socket` object is not a safe place to store the "current" event.